# jQuery: anonymous function onclick and onready

Tags: jquery

First of all, the code is working, but in my opinion not ideal.

I like anonymous functions in Javascript. So I can use an anonymous function when registering an `onclick` handler:

```
$(function()){
  $(".foo").on("click", function() {
     ..
  });
}
```

But sometimes, I realize that I need to call the function also `onReady`. So, I can convert the code to:

```
$(function()){

  function bar() { .. }

  $(".foo").on("click", bar);

  bar(); //'onload'
}
```

But thats a lot of work! (laziness is a good characteristic of a programmer). I have to create a non-anonymous function, change the onclick registrion etc. Is it possible to keep the anonymous function?

In the ideal situation, I have something like:

```
$(function()){
  $(".foo").on("click onDomLoaded", function() {
     ..
  });
}
```

but thats not working.

*(only option I see is to extend the 'on' function, but that seems ugly)*

Comment: Your second code block correctly does what you want and is a good pattern to use for the use case you have described...why is it "a lot of work"? That's nonsense. If you need to call the same "anonymous" function in more than one place, it's best to **not** use an anonymous function.

Comment: It's clearly more work than it should be. I don't need it on more places, but on more events. With that reason, man should never use anonymous function, because, maybe in the future, we convert it to a regular function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of @tymejV was close, but I could have some undesired side effects - for example, already bounded click events. fortunately we have ['namespaced events'](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) in jQuery which solves the problem:

```
$(function()){
  $(".foo").on("click load.somenamespace", function() {
     ..
  }).trigger("load.somenamespace");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.click()` trailing to trigger on load:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
 ..
}).click(); //trigger on load
```

Comment: Nice, but I have two functions separately bind onclick on .foo, then both will fire? (seems wrong, but there is no guarantee this will not happen)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you.

```
$(function()){


  $(".foo").on("click", function(){ bar();});

  bar(); //'onload'
}

function bar() { .. }
```

Comment: this is the code that I provided, but a function call wrapped in a anonymous function. This is even more work...

Comment: sorry mistakenly typed

Comment: I think you can go with as per @tymeJV answer. Because I think on will not fire for all. If we use live for class file, it'll call only for the element we clicked. As per jquery plugin, if on is replaced live in the higher version, you can use on otherwise if there is a chance to use live, better you can go with that. That'll work.